# What role did Crunchyroll play in the production of Ojisan and Marshmallow?

Tags: anime-production, crunchyroll, ojisan-and-marshmallow

I noticed that Crunchyroll appears in the end credits of Ojisan and Marshmallow:

[image: end credits of Ojisan and Marshmallow]

Why? Did Crunchyroll play some role in the production other than just streaming the show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most simplistic answer is that before the Anime production was to be aired, the studio had tied up with the production houses Crunchyroll and billibilli.

On 5th Jan, Anime News Network had the following article http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/daily-briefs/2016-01-05/ojisan-and-marshmallow-credits-list-crunchyroll/.97209

> The official website for the television anime of Rekomaru Otoi's web manga Ojisan and Marshmallow (Ojisan to Marshmallow) lists media distribution service Crunchyroll and Chinese streaming site bilibili as being in charge of foreign business for the project.

The next day, crunchyroll confirmed this news. http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/daily-briefs/2016-01-06/crunchyroll-confirms-ojisan-and-marshmallow-anime-streaming/.97283

As @NatG has noted, the Show credits CrunchyRoll and BilliBilli for Foreign Collaboration. This doesn't mean they have contributed to the show. It just  provides them most probably with exclusive rights for the show as well as the responsibility of Marketing etc. in other countries. Such deals usually take place after the anime has started or even finished airing in Japan for foreign countries.

This step is inline with other Global Production houses which tie up with foreign media houses to increase their base. For Example, US TV Channels collaborate with Indian Channels to air the show on the same day/next day because the market for such shows is increasing in India.

So this is just a move by the Production team to collaborate with other media partners to take the anime to a wider audience.

Answer (score 0):

I looked for the kanji on top : 海外協力 it means foreign/abroad cooperation/collaboration.

Comment: This is true, but I think OP was looking for a little more detail as to what this collaboration actually entailed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but senshin is correct; I was looking for more detail about what they actually did.